# JQuery remove label checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, label

I have the following code to create checkboxes (puntosD is a div I created where I append the checkbox):

```
$("div.puntosD").append('<input type=\"checkbox\" id="checkpuntos" name="'+data[index].id+'" value="'+data[index].nombre+'"> '+data[index].nombre);
```

I have the following code to remove the checkboxes:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").next('label').remove();
$("input[type='checkbox']").remove();
```

This however only removes the actual boxes to tick but not the labels, how can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does that div.puntosD has only checkbox and labels that you want to remove? Or Are you trying to remove any specific checkbox and its label from that div?

Comment: your code does not append a label, just a number that is floating in space (data[index].nombre).

Answer (score 3):

How about this, wrap the checkbox and label in span:

```
$("div.puntosD").append('<span><input type=\"checkbox\" id="checkpuntos" name="'
     + data[index].id+'" value="'+data[index].nombre+'">'
     + data[index].nombre+'</span>');
```

remove the span:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").parent('span').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are trying to remove all the checkbox & label inside the div or remove specific checkbox & label inside the div.

You can use `.empty` on that div in case if you only had checkbox & label inside the div and you want to remove them all.

```
$('div.puntosD').empty();
```

If you want to remove specific, then wrap it with a span and remove the span using below code,

```
$(':checkbox[name="1"]').parent('span').remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/XNFJD/)** here